# How do I set the colour of my points on a scatterplot depending on the condition x < y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this scatterplot at the moment.

```
ggplot(pl, mapping = aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 1, color = "red")
```

which produces this

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apvgO.png)

I want to colour any points below the diagonal red and any above the diagonal green. So basically colour on the condition x < y. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the shape of one point or few points in a scatter plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652479/changing-the-shape-of-one-point-or-few-points-in-a-scatter-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `color` argument in the `ggplot()` function with a condition x<y, and adding `scale_color_identity()` :

```
 ggplot(pl, mapping = aes(x, y,color=ifelse(x<y,"green","red")))+
  
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 1, color = "red")+
  
  scale_color_identity()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with the condition, and use that to color code your plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pl %>% mutate(threshold = case_when(
  x < y ~ TRUE,
  x >= y ~ FALSE),
mapping = aes(x, y, color = threshold))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 1, color = "red")
```