# How to draw a scatter plot in two color using plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am drawing a scatter plot using plot in r, and I want to show to dot in two colors.

For example, as you can see in the plot, for those x are smaller than 7 (1~6), I want to color them with red; as for those x are larger or equal to 7(7~10), I want to color them with blue.

This is how I set my dataframe.

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1:10),y = c(15:6))
plot(df$x,df$y,pch = 16)
```

This is the scatter plot.

[image]

Thank you for answering.
If you have other solutions(ggplot), please share with me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the shape of one point or few points in a scatter plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652479/changing-the-shape-of-one-point-or-few-points-in-a-scatter-plot-in-r)

Comment: A little bit complicated but yes! ^^

Answer (score 1):

All you need to add is an `ifelse` command for the `col` argument:

```
plot(df$x,df$y,pch = 16, col = ifelse(df$x < 7, "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
        mutate(is_smaller = ifelse(x < 7, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x, y, col = is_smaller)) +
        geom_point(show.legend = F) +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red", "FALSE" = "blue"))
```

[image]