# Changing shape and size of single data point on a ggplot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get the data point corresponding to "Our Company" to be a triangle whereas all other data points would remain as circles.

Ideally, I would also like it to be bigger than the other data points.

I have found multiple options to change both the size and format but these apply to all data points, as opposed to a single one. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(reprex)

df <- data.frame(School_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 Score = c( 20, 23, 33, 40, 19, 36, 50, 49, 33, 10),
                 Company = c("Other","Other", "Other", "Other", "Other",
                             "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Our Company"))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(School_ID, -Score),
             Score,
             colour = Company)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  labs(x = "Companies", 
       y = "Score") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", 
                    labels = c("Other companies", "Our company"),
                    values = c("#21908CFF", "#440154FF")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     labels = c("Other companies", "Our company"),
                     values = c("#21908CFF", "#440154FF")) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6))) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67652574/16730940

Comment: Just add `shape = Company, size = Company` and add `scale_xxxx` calls to customise as you wish.

Comment: Thank you both, I really appreciate it. It is incredible how one can search for hours and someone else know the answer in seconds!